# Given the stdev of a dataset and the stdev of a subset, compute the stdev after the subset is removed

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I am given a set of basic metrics for a dataset, such as:

- mean
- standard deviation
- length

I am then given the same set of metrics for a subset of the dataset, for example, a set of outliers.

However, I do not have access to the individual values within the dataset.

Given this, is it possible to compute the standard deviation of the dataset with the subset removed?

Comment: Yes: you can work out the sum of terms and the sum of squares

Comment: Messy, but possible. $(n+m)\bar X = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i +\sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m} X_i.$ If you know LHS and last sum, you can find first sum, and hence sample mean of smaller sample.  // Then $(n+m-1)S^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{n+m}(X_i - \bar X)^2
= \sum_{i=1}^{n+m}X_i^2 - (n+m)\bar X^2.$
The key step is to split each of the sums into two parts (as for the mean), and back-solve for
the parts relevant to the first sample.

Comment: While $(n-1)S^2 = \sum_i X_i^2-n\bar X^2$ can be proved with algebra, the two terms on RHS can be very large and their difference is not always computationally stable. So, in practice, you need to use this 'identity' with care,